# Running NodeJs kubernetes client example error

Tags: node.js, azure, kubernetes

I am following this link:
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript

and trying to list pods in the given namespace, here the code that I am referring:

```
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');

const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();

const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);

k8sApi.listNamespacedPod('abc').then((res) => {
    console.log(res.body);
});
```

I have successfully logged in to Kubernetes console, In the console, I am able to do the normal operation, but when I am running this code I am getting below error:

```
(node:30816) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Token is expired!
    at CloudAuth.updateAccessToken (D:\project\IOT-KT\dl\node_modules\@kubernetes\client-node\dist\cloud_auth.js:46:19)
    at CloudAuth.getToken (D:\project\IOT-KT\dl\node_modules\@kubernetes\client-node\dist\cloud_auth.js:24:18)
    at CloudAuth.<anonymous> (D:\project\IOT-KT\dl\node_modules\@kubernetes\client-node\dist\cloud_auth.js:15:32)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at D:\project\IOT-KT\dl\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:110:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (D:\project\IOT-KT\dl\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:106:16)
    at CloudAuth.applyAuthentication (D:\project\IOT-KT\dl\node_modules\@kubernetes\client-node\dist\cloud_auth.js:14:24)
    at KubeConfig.<anonymous> (D:\project\IOT-KT\dl\node_modules\@kubernetes\client-node\dist\config.js:299:37)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
(node:30816) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:30816) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Just wanted to mention that RBAC is enabled on k8s cluster

My Config file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1C..................Cg==
    server: https://<removed>.azmk8s.io:443
  name: removed>
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: removed>
    user: removed>
  name: removed>
current-context: removed>
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: removed>
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        apiserver-id: removed>
        client-id: removed>
        environment: removed>
        tenant-id: removed>
      name: azure
```

Please let me know what I am missing

Comment: Do you have a token in your kubeconfig? Are you using the same kubeconfig to login to console?

Comment: I am able to use kubectl, and in my .kube/config file I can see entry

Comment: Are you running this app inside the cluster as a pod or outside?

Comment: I am running this outside cluster, on my local machine

Comment: Do you see token in your kubeconfig file?

Comment: When I run these two commands, I am able to see my console:az aks get-credentials --resource-group <removed> --name <removed>
az aks browse --resource-group <removed> --name <removed> and

Comment: I will update the question with my config file

Comment: Are you able to use kubectl to run any command successfully?

Comment: Are you able to perform any operation with that token (looks like it's expired)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it appeared that as of now (Jan-2020) Javascript client library [doesn't  support](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/src/cloud_auth.ts#L62) automatic rewriting of the config when it refreshes a token.

```js
private updateAccessToken(config: Config) {
    let cmd = config['cmd-path'];
    if (!cmd) {
        throw new Error('Token is expired!');
```

The workaround is to validate it manually by runing `kubectl version` which will refresh the token in your `kubeconfig` file.

If that works, the option is to add the following to the `kubeconfig`:

```
user:
   ...
   cmd-path: kubectl
   cmd-args: version
```

Developers will definitely be ading better support for refreshing tokens to the client SDK.

Because there is already an [utility](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/src/config.ts#L352)
that calls `exportConfig()` to write the config into a string (which could then be written into a file), so it's possible to fix the behavior.

To do it right a large-ish refactor of the authenticator interface is required. That will be done under this [github issue track](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/issues/399).

Comment: Is this feature supported in other sdk like python or java or golang

Comment: That info can be taken from CHANGELOG.md files, but the general answer would be  'yes'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your token is empty which is the reason that throws the error. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/src/cloud_auth.ts#L61):

```
let cmd = config['cmd-path'];
        if (!cmd) {
            throw new Error('Token is expired!');
        }
```

And on my side, there is a `token` in the config file for the user in the users:

[image]

Maybe you can try to add the token in your config and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, I had posted the same question on GitHub https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/issues/389 and they suggested to run kubectl version command, and after running this command I was able to see access token field with value in config file, and I was successfully able to execute the program and it gave me correct output.